# Autogenerate shortcodes from an array of strings

Tags: php, shortcode

I have to create a lot of shortcodes of the form

```
function foobar_sc( $atts ) {
    remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', '<div class=con>[block slug=foobar]</div>' );
    add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
    return $content;
}
add_shortcode( 'foobar', 'foobar_sc' );
```

whose names are listed in an array

```
$shortcodes = array("foo", "bar", ...);
```

I tried with

```
$shortcodes = array("foo", "bar");
foreach ($shortcodes as $name) {
    add_shortcode( '$name', '$name_sc' );
    function $name_sc( $atts ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', '<div class=con>[block slug=$name]</div>' );
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        return $content;
    }
}
```

but I get the error **Fatal error: syntax error, unexpected '$name_sc' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' on line function $name_sc( $atts ) {**

Is it possible to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your shortcode name ('$name' ) is invalid. If you want to use the variable, it should be `add_shorcode( $name, ...`.  Also, the function name is invalid. Since you want to make it "dynamic" (I'm assuming you want it to be {$name}_sc, then maybe you should use an anonymous function.

What you have is somewhat unconventional (IMO), so I don't know if this will work, but try this:

```
$shortcodes = array("foo", "bar");
foreach ($shortcodes as $name) {
    add_shortcode( $name, function ( $atts ) use ( $name ) {
        remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        $content = apply_filters( 'the_content', '<div class=con>[block slug=' . $name . ']</div>' );
        add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
        return $content;
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works in the sense that the shortcodes are generated, but it seems like that the only problem is the variable `name` in line 5. I tried by substituting `'<div class=con>[block slug=' . $name . ']</div>'` with `'[slug=' . $name . ']'` and the output is `[slug=]`. Moreover the plugin Query Monitor says there is a PHP error `Undefined variable: name` for each auto generated shortcode. Is there a way to solve?

Comment: You need to use the `use` keyword so that the `$name` is available inside the closure (anonymous function): `add_shortcode( $name, function ( $atts ) use ( $name ) {`

Comment: ahhh... good point. Or alternatively, you could make it global.  I edited to apply `use()`

Comment: Note also that the shortcode tag is available as the third input argument of the callback.

Comment: i.e. `add_shortcode( $name, function ( $atts, $content, $name ) {`